# Does the number of isomorphisms equal the order of $Aut(G,H)$ if $ G$ and $ H$ are isomorphic groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ and $H$ be isomorphismc groups. Is the order of $Aut(G,H)$ equal to the number of isomorphisms between $G$ and $H$?

Comment: Sure. Informally $G$ and $H$ are "the same."

Comment: $\mathrm{Iso} ( G, H )$ is a better notation than $\mathrm{Aut} ( G, H )$ in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

I take it that you are asked whether the number of automorphisms of $G$ is equal to the number of *isomorphisms* from $G$ to $H$. Informally, the answer is obviously yes: $G$ and $H$ are abstractly the same.

Additional writing will only succeed in making things less clear. But here goes. Let $A$ be the set of automorphisms of $G$, and let $B$ be the set of isomorphisms from $G$ to $H$. We establish a bijection $f$ from $A$ to $B$.

Let $\gamma$ be a **fixed** isomorphism from $G$ to $H$. If $\phi$ is any automorphism of $g$, let $f(\phi)=\gamma\circ \phi$. It is easy to verify that $f(\phi)$ is an isomorphism from $G$ to $H$, and that $f$ is  bijective.